# sqlalchemy setting a relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a relationship between the two tables.

When instantiating a model I get the following error:

```
from core.models import Activation
a = Activation()
ArgumentError: Class object expected, got 'Table(u'activations', MetaData(bind=Engine(postgresql+psycopg2://localhost:5432/mydb)), Column('id', Integer(), table=<activations>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('valid_until', DateTime(), table=<activations>), Column('code', Unicode(length=30), table=<activations>, nullable=False), Column('created_by', Unicode(length=16), table=<activations>, nullable=False), schema=None)'.
```

core/models.py

```
class ActivationMixin(Base):

  @declared_attr
  def code(self):
    return Column(Unicode(30), nullable=False, unique=True)

  @declared_attr
  def valid_until(self):
    return Column(DateTime, nullable=True)

  @declared_attr
  def created_by(self):
    return Column(Unicode(16), nullable=False)

  @classmethod
  def get_by_code(cls, request, code):
    session = get_session(request)
    return session.query(cls).filter(cls.code == code).first()

  def __init__(self, created_by='web', valid_until=None):
    """Create a new activation. *valid_until* is a datetime.
    It defaults to 3 days from current day.
    """
    self.code = generate_random_string(24)
    self.created_by = created_by

    if valid_until:
      self.valid_until = valid_until
    else:
      self.valid_until = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=3)

class Activation(ActivationMixin):
  pass
```

user/models.py

```
class User(Base):
  email = Column(Unicode(256), nullable=False, unique=True)
  status = Column(Boolean, default=False)
  salt = Column(Unicode(32), nullable=False)
  _password = Column('password', Unicode(256), nullable=False)
  logins = Column(Integer, default=0)
  last_login = Column(
      TIMESTAMP(timezone=False),
      default=func.now(),
      server_default=func.now(),
      nullable=False
  )
  account_type = Column(AccountType.db_type())

  @declared_attr
  def activation_id(self):
    return Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey('%s.id' % (Activation.__tablename__))
    )

  @property
  def is_activated(self):
    if self.activation_id is None:
      return True

    return False

  @declared_attr
  def activation(self):
    return relationship(
      Activation.__tablename__,
      backref=self.__tablename__
    )
```

The error is occures with the following declaration:

```
@declared_attr
def activation(self):
    return relationship(
      Activation.__tablename__,
      backref=self.__tablename__
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some code that you haven't posted since running just this code would give you other errors as well (e.g., related to the `__tablename__` attributes not being properly set). However, the actual error you are getting is probably related to this code...

```
@declared_attr
def activation(self):
    return relationship(
      Activation.__tablename__,
      backref=self.__tablename__
    )
```

According to the documentation for [relationship function](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship), the first argument should be...

> a mapped class, or actual Mapper instance, representing the target of
>   the relationship.

However, you are using the `__tablename__` attribute, which should be just by the name of the table (a string).

So, try changing this to...

```
@declared_attr
def activation(self):
    return relationship(
      Activation,
      backref=self.__tablename__
    )
```